# Magic folder name in URL

Tags: php, css, directory

I just killed two hours fighting with this. That is very frustrating.

**URLs with folder name "adsq" (there are others) -- don't see `css` files in PHP pages.**

Here are two same pages, the difference is only in folder name:

http://chengyangxj.com/adsq/index2.php

http://chengyangxj.com/ads/index2.php

One is working, the other `adsq` does not. It just doesn't see `css` file.

I tried it on 3 computers with different OS.

How is it possible?

Comment: What's your Directory Structure?

Comment: If you are referring to <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css123123.css"> I see it in both files.

Comment: This is awkward, both are working fine for me

Comment: @F4r-20 Same here, I can see both in red

Comment: Let me guess: you have some ad-blocker enabled...

Comment: check for uppercase letters in your folder structure, it some hosts require your urls to be, by-the-letter, ie: http:/test.com/UpperCase/ wont work if you type, http://test.com/uppercase/

Comment: ...and it's blocking the "ads" in the URL.

Comment: @Passerby  Ad block is for blocking ads, not CSS

Comment: Both links are working fine here. Try accessing from http://www.pagewash.com/

Comment: @Mr.Alien Some ad-blockers work by URL matching, so if you block something like `*/ads/*`, it will be block, whatever content type that is.

Comment: Adblock Plus made this. I have it both on FF and Chrome. Turning it off make everything working again.

Comment: @Passerby That's so cruel :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your CSS is being blocked by addblockers, try linking the css using an absolute path in a folder not containing the word "ads"

e.g

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/mystyle.css">
```